# Objective function result : R's Nloptr vs Excel's GRG

Tags: r, excel, nonlinear-optimization

For a non-linear minimization optimization problem that I have, I am getting better objective function value in Excel(15) as compared to nloptr (73).

the nloptr is setup as:

```
opts = list("algorithm"="NLOPT_LN_COBYLA",
            "xtol_rel"=1.0e-8, "maxeval"= 10000)
lb = vector("numeric",length= length(my.data.var))

result <- nloptr(my.data.var,eval_f = Error.func,lb=lb,
                 ub = c(Inf,1,1,1,1,1,Inf,1,1,1,1,1,Inf,1,1,1,1,1,Inf,1,1,1,1,1),eval_g_ineq=constraint.func,opts = opts)
```

As observed even with 10000 as maximum evaluations, the objective function is way off as compared to Excel's GRG which solved it in 200 iterations.

Is there a way to improve the objective function value from nloptr? I am new to R so maybe you can shed some light on it.

Comment: Have you tried just using base R's `optim` function? I've obtained good results using that in the past. Alternatively, you could also try the `nlsq` function from the `minpack.lm` package -- that is an implementation of the Levenberg-Marquardt nonlinear optimization algorithm.

Comment: @AlexeyShiklomanov: I can't use optim because it does not allow inequality constraints. Does nlsq offer users to add inequality constraints?

Comment: Doesn't it? The default methods don't allow it, but if you set the method to `"L-BFGS-B"`, that allows you to perform bounded optimization. At least according to the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html). But yes, the `minpack.lm::nls.lm` (not `nlsq`, sorry!) function allows you to pass lower and upper bounds to each parameter.

Comment: @AlexeyShiklomanov: Correct. but the problem has "inequality constraints" apart from upper & lower bounds.

Comment: I suspect this unanswered question would have gathered more interest had there been data to work with and included Excel output by which to judge the claim of "better".